# Webpacker can't find chartkick

Tags: activeadmin, webpacker, chartkick, ruby-on-rails-6

I followed the documentation from  https://chartkick.com/ on a fresh Rails 6 install but I get the following:

```
Webpacker can't find chartkick in /home/sbstn/codes/desafio_latam/g24/chart_demo/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-0db4c39e559fa03658c6.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-0db4c39e559fa03658c6.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-0db4c39e559fa03658c6.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-0db4c39e559fa03658c6.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've made a partial with the following and rendered inside an ActiveAdmin panel:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag "application", "chartkick" %>
<% my_chart = {"ejemplo1": 20, "ejemplo2": 30} %>
<%= bar_chart my_chart %>
```

But plain simple examples form de oficial documentation didn't work on a normal view either.

Could you please provide some advice on how to integrate chartkick with webpacker and activeadmin

Answer (score 1):

It was my fault. Adding the gem is a must even if you add the requirements with yarn.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, that helped me. Unfortunately, it's absolutely not clear to me either (like it was for you) when to add a gem even when you add the whole stuff via yarn. Sometimes it's needed, sometimes not.